# GMSMapView show GMSMarker count when zoom in or out in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, gmsmapview

I'm using **GoogleMaps** in **iOS** to show the merchants location and i successfully placing all markers based on merchants location.

Now my requirement is, i want to show **markers count** while tapping to **zoom out** or **zoom in** as shown below.

[image: picture1] [image: picture2]

Please guide me...
My code was in Objective-C

Comment: which merchant count you want to show ? whole mp merchant count or only visible merchant on map ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to cluster the markers. Please check out this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/marker-clustering